# If Unix socket `SOCK_STREAMS` are unidirectional, how is node-ipc bidirectional?

Tags: node.js, sockets, unix, node-ipc

AFAIK, if a unix socket is created as type `SOCK_STREAMS` then it's unidirectional, and if `SOCK_DGRAM` then it's bidirectional.

I'm looking at using [`node-ipc`](https://github.com/RIAEvangelist/node-ipc) for IPC via unix sockets. It has an example of a [client](https://github.com/RIAEvangelist/node-ipc/blob/master/example/unixWindowsSocket/rawBuffer/hello-client.js) and [server](https://github.com/RIAEvangelist/node-ipc/blob/master/example/unixWindowsSocket/rawBuffer/world.server.js) that communicate supposedly via a unidirectional unix socket `SOCK_STREAMS` - yet seems to send messages in both directions.

What am I missing? Is the same socket path being used in two directions? Is it really using `SOCK_STREAMS`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> > AFAIK, if a unix socket is created as type SOCK_STREAMS then it's unidirectional, and if SOCK_DGRAM then it's bidirectional.

No. Domain SOCK_STREAMS are bi-directional as in the case of internet SOCK_STREAMS.